# Floppy Drive Connector to CF Card Reader with USB Port

Tags: hard-drive, motherboard, floppy, compact-flash

I bought an old floppy drive from a local market and just realized that my board isn't compatible. And I'm wondering, will it work if I connect my floppy drive to a cf card reader which has same number of pins? I know it's silly :p

Comment: How about this as an alternative http://www.techgeekshop.com/product/?id=1092954

Comment: @cybernard Yes I've looked into it. I'm trying to find a way without spending money :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless your CF card reader was built to be plugged into a floppy interface, no you can't.

A floppy drive interface is fairly "dumb".  It requires the controller to do everything, such as individual motor stepping and interpreting the analog read off the disk.